# C: prompt input one line at a time and check

Tags: c, loops, printf, scanf, user-input

Problem statement:
Loop 5 times. Each time, ask the user for an integer, check that the input received is that type, and then ask for another input until the user has given ﬁve correct inputs. The output of this program should look like this, assuming that the user gives ﬁve correct inputs of type int:

Hello! Please give me an integer: 0
Thanks! Please give me another integer: 1
Thanks! Please give me another integer: 1
Thanks! Please give me another integer: 2
Thanks! Please give me another integer: 3
Thanks! I am happy with five integers.

My attempts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int invalid(x)  
{  
    printf("\nThat was not an integer, please give me an integer: ");  
    scanf("%d", &x);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, x;

    printf("Hello! Please give me an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
            if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
            {
                    invalid(x);
            }
    printf("\nThanks! Please give me another integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
            if(scanf("%d", &b) != 1)
            {
                    invalid(x);
            }
    printf("\nThanks! Please give me another integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
            if(scanf("%d", &c) != 1)
            {
                    invalid(x);
            }
    printf("\nThanks! Please give me another integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
            if(scanf("%d", &d) != 1)
            {
                    invalid(x);
            }
    printf("\nThanks! Please give me another integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &e);
            if(scanf("%d", &e) != 1)
            {
                    invalid(x);
            }
    printf("\nThanks! I am happy with five integers.\n");
    return 0;
}


// Failed attempt to use a loop //
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     printf("Thanks! Please give me another integer: ");
     scanf("%d", &y);
              if(scanf("%d", &y) != 1)
              {
                     invalid(y);
              }
 }







do
{
     printf ("Thanks! Please give me another integer: ", );
     scanf("%d", &x);
         for(scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
         {
              printf("That was not an integer, please give me an integer: ")
              scanf("%d", &x);
         }
         i++;
} while (i < 4);
```

Common outputs that I get from the first input being a letter or non-integer:

```
Hello! Please give me an integer: d  
That was not an integer, please give me an integer: Thanks! Please give me another integer:  
That was not an integer, please give me an integer: Thanks! Please give me another integer:  
That was not an integer, please give me an integer: Thanks! Please give me another integer:  
That was not an integer, please give me an integer: Thanks! Please give me another integer:  
That was not an integer, please give me an integer: Thanks! I am happy with five integers.
```

Comment: I dont know C very well, but it looks like you are executing scanf() twice. I think you should store the first one in a variable and then use it in the if().

Comment: Problem statement said to create a "loop"... you didn't... you used simple sequence.  Perhaps use a "while", or a "do while", or maybe even a "for"...

Comment: When `scanf()` fails to convert `d` into an integer, it leaves `d` in the input for the next input operation.  Since that's another attempt to convert to `d` to an integer, it fails again, and the process gets boring.  If the input fails to convert, you probably need to gobble to the end of the line: `static inline void gobble(void) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ; }` and call `gobble();` after you detect a problem.

Comment: You're also using a K&R style function where the parameter `x` is implicitly typed `int`.  That's been invalid according to standard C for the whole of this millennium.  Time to upgrade to 21st Century C; leave it to old fogies like me to deal with super-antiquated code (and even I don't write in that style — but I do get to fix code that was written like that).  Note that you alter the argument `x`, but that never affects anything in the `main()` function.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and the documentation of [standard IO functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) that you are using. Be aware that *stdio* is buffering. Consider using [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) or put `\n` at *end* of `printf` control format strings. Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use array to store 5 numbers (or 4, or any other amount greater than 1)
2. In any case you should use loop to ask 5 (or any other series of numbers) and here `for` loop will be good
3. You should analyse value returned by `scanf` to check if the input was correct, and re ask if value is wrong (this can be also loop, but `do..while` is prehereble) after incorrect characters removed from input buffer.

**UPDATE**

My version of the prog:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_CNT 5

int main(void)
{
    int i, res, c;
    int num[NUM_CNT]; // array for all your numbers
    printf("Hello!\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CNT; i++) {
        printf("Please give me an integer: ");
        do {
            res = scanf("%d", &num[i]);
            if ( res ) {
                printf("Thanks!\n");
            } else {
                printf("That was not an integer, please give me an integer: ");
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // clean input buffer
            }
        } while(res != 1);
    }
    printf("I am happy with five integers.\n");
    // just to see all the numbers
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CNT; i++) {
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You are free to remake your code using my ideas.